# IronPython indexer parameter compilation error

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am pretty new to IronPython. And I have a question about accessing element by indexer. For example in C# we can write something like this: 
[image: Everything is ok.]

But when I try to do in IronPython something equivalent:

[image: Compilation error]

It tells me that there is "unexpected token '+='". I used '+=' increment operation because there is no such post-increment operation '++' in IronPython. I am using IronPython 2.7.

Can anyone help me with this? What should I change to make my IronPython code compile and keep functionality the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python prevents that kind of side effect syntax.

No way around this: you have to do:

```
rval = ints[index]
index += 1
return rval
```

or

```
index += 1
return ints[index-1]
```